# Name of pattern

Tags: design-patterns

May be wrong place to ask (please direct) but:

I often use a variance of the Strategy pattern where I write like this:

```
interface IA
{
   bool CanHandle(T someParameter)
   void Handle(T someParamter)
}
class A1:IA {}
class A2:IA {}
```

I then have a class where `IEnumerable<IA>` is injected, the First/Single/All of the instances is found through `CanHandle()` and called on `Handle()`.

IS there a name for this pattern?

Comment: There is no GoF pattern that fits this implementation precisely. It's tempting to say Chain of Responsibility; but that pattern is recursive (not iterative) and defines no more than one handler per event. I'm curious, are you able to handle the parameter `T` without type-checking and casting it?

Comment: Thanks, for chipping in, Jaco. T was just a type, not a generic type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the .NET world this is known as the *Test/Doer* idiom. It's isomorphic to another .NET idiom usually known as *TryParse*, and [both are isomorphic to the Maybe container](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/07/15/tester-doer-isomorphisms), which [can be defined from an F-algebra](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/05/20/maybe-catamorphism). It doesn't get much more foundational than that.